# Multidimensional Array does not hold values

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have been trying to see where the problem is but couldnt find it. Every time, the values of array memory gives me 0, even though int count works and keeps counting as the struct data value, only array does not save the value.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#define SIZE 1000

struct registers
 {
   int data;     
 } registerX;

void first(int *counter, struct registers* X1, int m[][2])
{
 int value;
 printf("Enter the value for the X\n");
 scanf("%d", &value);
 X1->data = value;
 m[*counter][1] = X1->data;
 *counter = ++*counter;   
}


int main()
{
int memory[SIZE][2];
int choice;
int count = 0;
printf("Enter the instruction number:\n");

while(choice != 107)

 {

   scanf("%d", &choice);
   if(choice == 101)
   {
       memory[count][0] = 101;
       first(&count, &registerX, memory);
       printf("%d\n", memory[count][1]);
        printf("%d\n", memory[count][0]);
   } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate. `*counter = ++*counter;` has undefined behaviour. (E.g. see http://stackoverflow.com/q/4176328/596781, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior.)

Comment: `printf("%d\n", memory[count][1]);` : `count` update to +1.

Answer (score 1):

You have some problems in your code.

Firstly,`choice` in `while(choice != 107)` is uninitialized. To fix it,use a `do...while` loop instead of a `while` loop as you want the loop body to execute once before checking the condition.

Secondly,`*counter = ++*counter;` undefined behaviour has KerrekSB [points out in his comment](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/27203924/multidimensional-array-does-not-hold-values#comment42890485_27203924). To fix it,use `(*counter)++;`.

Lastly,you print uninitialized elements of your array in the last two `printf`s. The reason is that you increment `*counter` in the function which will also modify `count` in `main` as `counter` is a pointer which points to the address of `count`.